# How to redirect post feed to main blog feed with htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have one question: **How to redirect post feed to main blog feed with htaccess?**

for example: myblog.com/18364552/post-name/feed/ to myblog.com/feed/

thank

Comment: What other rules do you already have on your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

The rewriterule you are looking for looks something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/feed/?$ /feed [R,L]
```

It should be self-explenatory. Please refer to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if you don't understand some of the syntax.

---

**Regex explaination**

- `[0-9]` means match a character that is in the range of `0` to `9` (e.g. any number).
- `[0-9]{4}` means match 4 numbers.
- Similary `[0-9]{1,2}` means match 1 or 2 numbers.
- `[^/]` means match any character but the `/` character.
- `[^/]+` means match 1 or more characters that are not a `/`.
- `/?` means match 0 or 1 `/` character.
- `^...$` means match the beginning of the string (`^`) and the end of the string `$`, forcing it to match the entire string, even if this regex could match a substring of the entire string.

Comment: thanks for your fast response. but unfortunately its not working.

my url structure is number not based on year, ex myblog/12478/post-name/

thanks again

Comment: I'll not edit my answer, as it answers the question in the actual question (e.g. it now makes sense to someone that has a similar problem). If you understand what this regex does, you should have no trouble changing it to what you need.

Comment: ya, but i dont know why it doesn't work. what if using redirectmatch 301? is it possible? thanks

Comment: This rule needs to be before the internal rewrite. I am not 100% sure how wordpress works.